# Selenium-Webdriver allows opening of multiple tabs in one window but not when loading a profile?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to load multiple tabs of websites via geckodriver and I am having success only when loading them as follows:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(2)

driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get('https://yahoo.com/?p=us')

driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
driver.get('https://youtube.com')
```

But when I try to load a profile like so:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

profile_path = (<path to profile folder>)
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(2)

driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get('https://yahoo.com/?p=us')

driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
driver.get('https://youtube.com')
```

The websites open on separate windows. How do I open them on one window while still being able to load a profile?